# What do the author numbers in PHI5.3 mean?

Tags: resource-request, text-corpus, packhum-corpus

In Packhum's Latin corpus (PHI5.3), each author is identified by a four-digit code. For example, Caesar is 0448, while Cicero is 0474, and Seneca the Younger is 1017. Each work is then given a three-digit number (counting up from 001), so Seneca's *Oedipus* is filed under "1017 006".

Do the author numbers have any meaning? Unlike the work numbers, they don't seem to be sequential (there is no 0449, 0475, or 1018, for example), which makes me think they're conveying some other information.

Comment: Is there a (full) list of the author numbers somewhere? It's easier to see patterns in more data.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta [Here](https://latin.packhum.org/canon) and [here](https://github.com/cltk/cltk/blob/dev/src/cltk/readers/phi5_index.py), though neither is in numerical order unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

In case it helps someone figure this out, here are the authors in numerical order.
This is a sorted version of [the list of authors](https://github.com/cltk/cltk/blob/dev/src/cltk/readers/phi5_index.py).
The years indicate when the person lived.
When unsure, it gives known dates of consulship or other activities.
In some cases the name given in the list is not unique enough to identify the person, and I may have misidentified some authors.

The authors appear to be in rough but not exact chronological order.

(Yes, [tables are now possible on our site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/321340)!)

| Code | Years | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LAT0002 | 153 BCE or 172 BCE | Titus Annius Luscus |
| LAT0004 | 340 BCE – ~280 BCE | Appius Claudius Caecus |
| LAT0005 | ? | Aquilius, comoed. |
| LAT0007 | ? | Atilius |
| LAT0010 | 85 BCE – 42 BCE (junior) / ? – 77 BCE (senior) | Marcus Iunius Brutus [iur.] |
| LAT0013 | ~220 BCE – ~166 BCE | Caecilius Statius |
| LAT0016 | ~180 BCE – 112 BCE | Lucius Calpurnius Piso Frugi |
| LAT0019 | ? | Gaius Papirius Carbo |
| LAT0022 | 234 BCE – 149 BCE | Marcus Porcius Cato, Cato |
| LAT0025 | ? | Marcus Porcius Cato M.f.M.n. |
| LAT0027 | ~200 BCE | Lucius Cincius Alimentus |
| LAT0028 | ~123 BCE | Lucius Coelius Antipater |
| LAT0031 | ~195 BCE – ~115 BCE | Cornelia, mater Gracchorum |
| LAT0034 | ? | Gaius Scribonius Curio avus |
| LAT0037 | ? | Gaius Scribonius Curio pater |
| LAT0043 | ~239 BCE – 169 BCE | Quintus Ennius |
| LAT0046 | ~50 BCE | Cornelius Epicadus |
| LAT0058 | ~145 BCE | Q. Fabius Maximus Servilianus |
| LAT0061 | ~270 BCE – ~200 BCE | Fabius Pictor |
| LAT0064 | ~150 BCE | Gaius Fannius |
| LAT0067 | ~80 CE – ~160 CE | Favorinus |
| LAT0070 | ~125 BCE | Gnaeus Gellius |
| LAT0073 | 154 BCE – 121 BCE | Gaius Sempronius Gracchus |
| LAT0076 | ? | Gaius Cassius Hemina |
| LAT0079 | ~150 BCE | Hostius |
| LAT0082 | ? | Decimus Iunius Silanus |
| LAT0085 | ~18 BCE – ? | Gaius Laelius Sapiens |
| LAT0088 | ~137 BCE | M. Aemilius Lepidus Porcina |
| LAT0091 | ? | Licinius Imbrex |
| LAT0094 | ~284 BCE – ~205 BCE | Lucius Livius Andronicus |
| LAT0097 | ~180 BCE – 103 BCE | Gaius Lucilius |
| LAT0100 | ? | Luscius Lanuvinus |
| LAT0103 | ? | Gnaeus Marcius vates |
| LAT0104 | ? – ~49 BCE | Gaius Memmius |
| LAT0106 | ? | Caecilius Metellus |
| LAT0109 | ? | Q. Caecilius Metellus Maced. |
| LAT0112 | ~270 BCE – ~201 BCE | Gnaeus Naevius |
| LAT0116 | 220 BCE – ~130 BCE | Marcus Pacuvius |
| LAT0117 | ? | Papinius, epigram. |
| LAT0118 | ? | L. Aemilius L.f.M.n. Paulus |
| LAT0119 | ~254 BCE – 184 BCE | Titus Maccius Plautus |
| LAT0122 | ? | Aulus Postumius Albinus |
| LAT0125 | ~176 BCE – 115 BCE | Publius Mucius Scaevola |
| LAT0127 | 235 BCE – 183 BCE | P. Cornel. Scipio Afr. ma. |
| LAT0128 | 185 BCE – 129 BCE | P. Cornel. Scipio Aem. Afr. |
| LAT0130 | 181 BCE – 132 BCE | P. Cornel. Scipio Nasica Ser. |
| LAT0134 | ~190 BCE – ~159 BCE | Publius Terentius Afer, Terence |
| LAT0137 | ~170 BCE | Titinius |
| LAT0140 | ? | Gaius Titius |
| LAT0143 | ? | Trabea |
| LAT0146 | ? | Sextus Turpilius |
| LAT0149 | 218 BCE | Carmen Arvale |
| LAT0300 | ~159 BCE – ~91 BCE | Sempronius Asellio |
| LAT0301 | ? | Gnaeus Domitius Ahenobarbus |
| LAT0302 | 143 BCE – 87 BCE | Marcus Antonius |
| LAT0303 | ~92 BCE | Aurelius Opillus |
| LAT0306 | ? | Carmen Devotionis |
| LAT0309 | ? | Carmen Evocationis |
| LAT0312 | ? | Fabius Dossennus |
| LAT0315 | ? | Marcus Iunius Gracchanus |
| LAT0321 | ? | Porcius Licinus |
| LAT0324 | ? | Saserna |
| LAT0327 | ? | L. Aelius Praeconinus Stilo |
| LAT0330 | ~100 BCE | Volcacius Sedigitus |
| LAT0400 | 170 BCE – ~86 BCE | Lucius Accius |
| LAT0401 | ? | Aufustius |
| LAT0402 | ~50 BCE | Valerius Aedituus |
| LAT0404 | ~75 BCE | Lucius Afranius |
| LAT0405 | ? | Clodius Tuscus |
| LAT0406 | ? | Publius Alfenus Varus |
| LAT0408 | 83 BCE – 30 BCE | Marcus Antonius triumvir |
| LAT0409 | ? – 42 BCE | Quintus Cornificius |
| LAT0410 | ? | Aprissius (?) |
| LAT0412 | ? | Gaius Aquilius Gallus |
| LAT0413 | ? | Gavius Bassus |
| LAT0414 | ? | Lucius Arruntius |
| LAT0416 | ? | Lucius Ateius Praetextatus |
| LAT0418 | ? – 77 BCE | Titus Quinctius Atta |
| LAT0419 | 114 BCE – 14 BCE | Lucius Orbilius Pupillus |
| LAT0420 | ? | Publius Aufidius Namusa |
| LAT0423 | ? | Lucius Herennius Balbus |
| LAT0425 | ? | Publius Rutilius Lupus |
| LAT0426 | ? | Bellum Africum [Anonymous] |
| LAT0428 | ? | Bellum Alexandrinum [Anonymous] |
| LAT0430 | ? | Bellum Hispaniense [Anonymous] |
| LAT0432 | 103 BCE – ? | Marcus Furius Bibaculus |
| LAT0436 | 85 BCE – 42 BCE (junior) / ? – 77 BCE (senior) | Marcus Iunius Brutus [tyr.] |
| LAT0442 | ~69 BCE | Aulus Caecina |
| LAT0444 | 82 BCE – ~45 BCE | Marcus Caelius Rufus |
| LAT0445 | ? | Gaius vel Lucius Caepasius |
| LAT0446 | ? | Quintus Servilius Caepio |
| LAT0448 | 100 BCE – 44 BCE | Gaius Iulius Caesar, Caesar |
| LAT0450 | ? | Lucius Iulius Caesar |
| LAT0451 | ? | Sinnius Capito |
| LAT0452 | ~130 BCE – 87 BCE | Gaius Iulius Caesar Strabo |
| LAT0454 | ? | Marcus Calidius |
| LAT0455 | ? | Gaius Calpurnius Piso |
| LAT0456 | 82 BCE – 47 BCE | Gaius Licinius Macer Calvus |
| LAT0458 | 106 BCE – ? | Publius Cannutius |
| LAT0460 | ? – 82 BCE | Gaius Papirius Carbo Arvina |
| LAT0466 | ? | Aulus Cascellius |
| LAT0469 | ? | Lucius Cassius Longinus |
| LAT0470 | 95 BCE – 46 BCE | Marcus Porcius Cato Uticensis |
| LAT0472 | ~84 BCE – ~54 BCE | Gaius Valerius Catullus |
| LAT0473 | 149 BCE – 87 BCE | Q. Lutatius Catulus iunior |
| LAT0474 | 106 BCE – 43 BCE | Marcus Tullius Cicero, Cicero, Tully |
| LAT0478 | 102 BCE – 43 BCE | Quintus Tullius Cicero |
| LAT0484 | ~200 BCE | Lucius Cincius |
| LAT0486 | ? – 44 BCE | Gaius Helvius Cinna |
| LAT0487 | ? | Publius Clodius Pulcher |
| LAT0488 | ? | Servius Clodius |
| LAT0490 | ? | Publius Cominius |
| LAT0492 | ? | Commentarii Augurum |
| LAT0494 | ? | Commentarii Consulares |
| LAT0496 | ? | Commentarius Anquisit. Sergii |
| LAT0498 | 124 BCE – 73 BCE | Gaius Aurelius Cotta |
| LAT0500 | 140 BCE – 91 BCE | Lucius Licinius Crassus |
| LAT0502 | ? – 25 CE | Aulus Cremutius Cordus |
| LAT0510 | ? | Publius Cornelius Dolabella |
| LAT0512 | ~97 BCE | Marcus Duronius |
| LAT0514 | ? | Egnatius |
| LAT0515 | ? | Sextus (vel Spurius) Ennius |
| LAT0516 | ? | Gaius Erucius |
| LAT0518 | ~100 BCE | Aulus Furius Antias |
| LAT0522 | ~25 BCE | Gaius Aelius Gallus |
| LAT0524 | 30 BCE – 26 CE | Gaius Cornelius Gallus, Gallus |
| LAT0526 | ? – 100 BCE | Gaius Servilius Glaucia |
| LAT0527 | ? | Gannius |
| LAT0528 | ~50 BCE | Granius Flaccus |
| LAT0530 | ~90 BCE – 43 BCE | Aulus Hirtius |
| LAT0532 | 114 BCE – 50 BCE | Quintus Hortensius Hortalus |
| LAT0533 | ~64 BCE – 17 CE | Gaius Iulius Hyginus |
| LAT0534 | ? | Iuventius, comoed. |
| LAT0535 | ? | Marcus Iuventius Laterensis |
| LAT0536 | ~105 BCE – 43 BCE | Decimus Laberius |
| LAT0537 | ? | Titus Labienus |
| LAT0538 | ~80 BCE | Laevius |
| LAT0540 | ? | Tullius Laurea |
| LAT0541 | ~90 BCE – ~48 BCE | Cn. Cornel. Lentulus Marcell. |
| LAT0546 | ~50 CE | Gaius Licinius Mucianus |
| LAT0550 | ~99 BCE – ~55 BCE | Titus Lucretius Carus |
| LAT0552 | ? | Quintus Lutatius Catulus |
| LAT0556 | ? | Gaius Licinius Macer |
| LAT0558 | ~70 BCE – 8 BCE | Gaius Cilnius Maecenas |
| LAT0560 | ? | Helvius Mancia |
| LAT0562 | ? | Manilius, poet. |
| LAT0564 | ~150 BCE | Manius Manilius |
| LAT0568 | ? | Gnaeus Matius |
| LAT0574 | ? | Gaius Memmius L. f. |
| LAT0576 | 103 BCE – 26 CE | M. Valerius Messalla Rufus |
| LAT0582 | ~160 BCE – 91 BCE | Q. Caecilius Metellus Numid. |
| LAT0584 | ? | Mimi Poetarum Incertorum |
| LAT0586 | ? | Mummius |
| LAT0587 | ? | Naevius, iunior |
| LAT0588 | ~110 BCE – ~25 BCE | Cornelius Nepos |
| LAT0590 | ~98 BCE – 45 BCE | Publius Nigidius Figulus |
| LAT0591 | ? | Ninnius Crassus |
| LAT0592 | ? | Novius, comoed. |
| LAT0594 | ? | Lucius Novius |
| LAT0596 | ? | Numitorius |
| LAT0600 | ? | Gaius Oppius |
| LAT0606 | ? | Lucius Marcius Philippus |
| LAT0614 | ? | Q. Pompeius Q.f.A.n. Rufus |
| LAT0615 | ? | Q. Pompeius Q.f.Q.n. Rufus |
| LAT0616 | ? | Pompilius |
| LAT0618 | ? | Lucius Pomponius Bononiensis |
| LAT0620 | ~48 BCE – ~14 BCE | Sextus Propertius |
| LAT0622 | ~60 BCE | Publilius Syrus |
| LAT0624 | ~50 BCE | Quintus Claudius Quadrigarius |
| LAT0625 | ? | Lucius Quinctius |
| LAT0628 | 158 BCE – ~75 BCE | Publius Rutilius Rufus |
| LAT0630 | ? | Sacra Argeorum |
| LAT0631 | ? | Gaius Sallustius Crispus |
| LAT0634 | ? | Santra |
| LAT0635 | ? | Publius Saturius |
| LAT0636 | ? | Quintus Mucius Scaevola |
| LAT0638 | 140 BCE – 83 BCE | Q. Mucius Scaevola [pontifex] |
| LAT0640 | ? | Marcus Aemilius Scaurus |
| LAT0642 | ~200 BCE | Sevius Nicanor |
| LAT0644 | ? | Sextilius Ena |
| LAT0646 | ~120 BCE – 67 BCE | Lucius Cornelius Sisenna |
| LAT0648 | ? | Staberius Eros |
| LAT0650 | ? | Sueius |
| LAT0652 | ? | Lucius Cornelius Sulla |
| LAT0656 | ~105 BCE – 43 BCE | Servius Sulpicius Rufus |
| LAT0658 | ? | Tabulae Censoriae |
| LAT0660 | ~55 BCE – 19 BCE | Albius Tibullus |
| LAT0661 | ? | Ticidas |
| LAT0662 | ? – ~4 BCE | Marcus Tullius Tiro |
| LAT0664 | ~84 BCE – 4 CE | Gaius Trebatius Testa |
| LAT0668 | ? | Gnaeus Tremelius Scrofa |
| LAT0670 | ? | Quintus Aelius Tubero |
| LAT0672 | ? | Turranius Niger |
| LAT0674 | ? | Valerius, comoed. |
| LAT0676 | ~50 BCE | Valerius Antias |
| LAT0678 | ~135 BCE – 82 BCE | Quintus Valerius Soranus |
| LAT0680 | ~50 BCE | Gaius Valgius Rufus |
| LAT0682 | ~74 BCE – 14 BCE | Lucius Varius Rufus |
| LAT0684 | 116 BCE – 27 BCE | Marcus Terentius Varro, Varro |
| LAT0686 | 82 BCE – ~35 BCE | P. Terentius Varro Atacinus |
| LAT0690 | 70 BCE – 19 BCE | Publius Vergilius Maro, Virgil, Vergil |
| LAT0692 | ? | Appendix Vergiliana |
| LAT0694 | ? | Volumnius |
| LAT0703 | ? | Arbonius Silo |
| LAT0706 | ? | Carmen de Bello Aegyptiaco |
| LAT0709 | ~50 BCE | Domitius Marsus |
| LAT0721 | ? | Antonius Panurgus |
| LAT0724 | ? | Cloatius Verus |
| LAT0727 | ? | Cornificius Longus |
| LAT0730 | ? | Tarquitius Priscus |
| LAT0800 | ~0 | Albinovanus Pedo |
| LAT0803 | ~9 BCE – ~76 CE | Quintus Asconius Pedianus |
| LAT0806 | ? | Gaius Ateius Capito |
| LAT0809 | ~20 CE | Aufidius Bassus |
| LAT0812 | ? | Gaius Caesius Bassus |
| LAT0815 | ~22 CE | Bruttedius Niger |
| LAT0821 | ? | Bucolica Einsidlensia |
| LAT0824 | ? | Cn. Arulenus Caelius Sabinus |
| LAT0827 | ? | Caesellius Vindex |
| LAT0830 | ? | Titus Calpurnius Siculus |
| LAT0836 | ~25 BCE – ~50 CE | Aulus Cornelius Celsus |
| LAT0842 | ? | Gaius Clodius Licinus |
| LAT0845 | ? | L. Iunius Moderatus Columella |
| LAT0851 | ~0 | Cornelius Severus |
| LAT0854 | ? | Cornificius Gallus |
| LAT0857 | ~60 CE | Lucius Annaeus Cornutus |
| LAT0860 | ~50 CE | Quintus Curtius Rufus |
| LAT0863 | ? | Dorcatius |
| LAT0866 | ? | Fenestella |
| LAT0869 | ~55 BCE – 20 CE | Marcus Verrius Flaccus |
| LAT0875 | ? | Cn. Cornel. Lentulus Gaetulicus |
| LAT0878 | ~40 BCE – 33 CE | Gaius Asinius Gallus |
| LAT0881 | ? | Claudius Caesar Germanicus |
| LAT0884 | ? | Gracchus, trag. |
| LAT0887 | ? | Grattius |
| LAT0890 | ? | Homerus Latinus |
| LAT0893 | 65 BCE – 8 BCE | Quintus Horatius Flaccus, Horace |
| LAT0899 | ? | Hyginus Astronomus |
| LAT0902 | ? | Iulius Africanus |
| LAT0905 | ? – 10 CE | Marcus Antistius Labeo |
| LAT0908 | ~50 CE | Attius Labeo |
| LAT0911 | ? | Laus Pisonis |
| LAT0914 | X~60 BCE – ~15 CE | Titus Livius, Livy |
| LAT0917 | 39 CE – 65 CE | Marcus Annaeus Lucanus |
| LAT0920 | ~50 CE | Lucilius iunior |
| LAT0923 | ? | Aemilius Macer |
| LAT0926 | ~50 CE | Marcus Manilius, Manilius |
| LAT0929 | ~43 CE | Pomponius Mela |
| LAT0932 | ? | M. Valerius Messalla Corvinus |
| LAT0935 | ? | Iulius Modestus |
| LAT0938 | ? | Iulius Montanus |
| LAT0944 | 37 CE – 68 CE | Imperator Nero |
| LAT0959 | 43 BCE – 18 CE | Publius Ovidius Naso |
| LAT0963 | ~40 CE | Quintus Remmius Palaemon |
| LAT0966 | ? | Passienus Crispus |
| LAT0969 | 34 CE – 62 CE | Aulus Persius Flaccus |
| LAT0972 | ~27 CE – 66 CE | Petronius |
| LAT0975 | ~15 BCE – ~50 CE | Phaedrus |
| LAT0978 | 24 CE – 79 CE | Gaius Plinius Secundus, Pliny |
| LAT0981 | ? | Gaius Asinius Pollio |
| LAT0984 | ~50 BCE | Pompeius Trogus |
| LAT0987 | ~40 CE | Publius Pomponius Secundus |
| LAT0990 | ? | Precatio Omnium Herbarum |
| LAT0993 | ? | Precatio Terrae |
| LAT0996 | ~25 CE – 105 CE | Marcus Valerius Probus |
| LAT1000 | ? | Pupius (?) |
| LAT1002 | ~35 CE – ~100 CE | Marcus Fabius Quintilianus |
| LAT1005 | ? | Rabirius |
| LAT1011 | ~1 CE – ~50 CE | Scribonius Largus |
| LAT1014 | ~54 BCE – ~39 CE | Lucius Annaeus Seneca senior |
| LAT1017 | ~4 BCE – 65 CE | Lucius Annaeus Seneca iunior |
| LAT1020 | ~45 CE – ~96 CE | Publius Papinius Statius |
| LAT1023 | ? | Sulpicia, Caleni uxor |
| LAT1029 | ? | Turnus |
| LAT1032 | ? | Vagellius |
| LAT1035 | ? – ~90 CE | Gaius Valerius Flaccus |
| LAT1038 | ? | Valerius Maximus |
| LAT1041 | ? | Pseudo-Varro |
| LAT1044 | ~19 BCE – ~31 CE | Velleius Paterculus |
| LAT1047 | ? | Veranius |
| LAT1050 | 15 CE – 97 CE | Lucius Verginius Rufus |
| LAT1053 | ? | Vibius Crispus |
| LAT1056 | ~75 BCE – ~10 BCE | Vitruvius |
| LAT1100 | ~120 CE | Calpurnius Flaccus |
| LAT1103 | ? | Priapea |
| LAT1203 | ~0 | Alfius Avitus |
| LAT1206 | ? | Lucius Ampelius |
| LAT1209 | ? | Annianus |
| LAT1212 | ? | Apuleius Madaurensis |
| LAT1218 | ? | Sentius Augurinus |
| LAT1221 | 63 BCE – 14 CE | C. Iul. Caes. Augustus Octavianus |
| LAT1224 | 121 CE – 180 CE | Marcus Aurelius |
| LAT1227 | ? | Balbus, grom. |
| LAT1229 | ~150 CE | Flavius Caper |
| LAT1234 | ? | Didascaliae et Argum. in Plautum |
| LAT1235 | ? | Didascaliae et Per. in Terentium |
| LAT1236 | ~175 CE | Sextus Pompeius Festus |
| LAT1242 | ? | Annius Florus |
| LAT1245 | ~40 CE – 103 CE | Sextus Iulius Frontinus |
| LAT1248 | ~100 CE – ~168 CE | Marcus Cornelius Fronto |
| LAT1251 | ? | Gaius, iur., Gaius |
| LAT1254 | ~125 CE – ~185 CE | Aulus Gellius |
| LAT1257 | ~150 CE | Granius Licinianus |
| LAT1260 | 76 CE – 138 CE | Hadrianus |
| LAT1263 | ? | Hyginus, myth. |
| LAT1266 | ~100 CE | Hyginus Gromaticus |
| LAT1276 | ~100 CE | Decimus Iunius Iuvenalis, Juvenal |
| LAT1279 | ? | Laelius Felix |
| LAT1282 | ? | Lentulus, mimus |
| LAT1285 | ~110 CE – 175 CE | Lucius Volusius Maecianus |
| LAT1291 | ? | Marianus |
| LAT1294 | 41 CE – ~103 CE | Marcus Valerius Martialis |
| LAT1297 | ? | Marullus |
| LAT1306 | ? | Lucius Neratius Priscus |
| LAT1318 | 61 CE – ~113 CE | C. Plinius Caecilius Secundus, Pliny |
| LAT1321 | ~140 CE | Sextus Pomponius |
| LAT1327 | ? | Sabidius |
| LAT1336 | ? | Scaevus Memor |
| LAT1339 | ? | Septimius Serenus |
| LAT1342 | ? | Siculus Flaccus |
| LAT1345 | ~28 CE – ~103 CE | Silius Italicus |
| LAT1348 | ~69 CE – ~125 CE | Gaius Suetonius Tranquillus |
| LAT1351 | ~56 CE – ~120 CE | Cornelius Tacitus |
| LAT1357 | 53 CE – 117 CE | Imp. Marcus Ulpius Traianus, Trajan |
| LAT1363 | ~100 CE | Aemilius Asper |
| LAT1370 | ~125 CE | Quintus Terentius Scaurus |
| LAT1374 | ~150 CE | Velius Longus |
| LAT1377 | ? | Fragmenta Bobiensia |
| LAT1380 | ? | Philumenus medicus |
| LAT1500 | ? | Altercatio Hadr. et Epicteti |
| LAT1506 | ? | Anonymi Fragmenta de Iure Fisci |
| LAT1512 | ~150 CE | Pomponius Porphyrio |
| LAT1515 | ? | Quintus Serenus (Sammonicus) |
| LAT1518 | ~175 CE | Terentianus Maurus |
| LAT1604 | ? | Iulius Atherianus |
| LAT1672 | ? | Iulius Valerius |
| LAT1908 | ? | Gallus Antipater |
| LAT2000 | ~400 CE | Ablabius |
| LAT2002 | ? | Albinus, poet. |
| LAT2003 | ? | Caelius Apicius |
| LAT2028 | ~350 CE | Chalcidius |
| LAT2097 | ? | Sextus Paconianus |
| LAT2123 | ~350 CE | Publilius Optatianus Porfyrius |
| LAT2150 | ~300 CE – ~375 CE | Zeno of Verona |
| LAT2300 | ? | Aemilius Sura |
| LAT2301 | ? – 526 CE | Q. Aurelius Memmius Symmachus |
| LAT2302 | ? – 376 CE | L. Aurel. Avianius Symmachus |
| LAT2305 | ~450 CE | Caelius Aurelianus |
| LAT2331 | ? | Scriptores Historiae Augustae |
| LAT2335 | ? | Anonymi de Differentiis [Fronto] |
| LAT2349 | ~400 CE | Maurus Servius Honoratus, Servius |
| LAT2434 | ? | Hilarius Arelatensis |
| LAT2456 | ? | Parthenius Presbyter |
| LAT2468 | 354 CE – 430 CE | Aurelius Augustinus |
| LAT2806 | ? | Iustinianus, Justinian, Digest |
| LAT3211 | ? | Argum. Aen. et Tetrast. |
| LAT9221 | ? | Paulus Quaestor |
| LAT9254 | ? | Titius, gram. |
| LAT9500 | ? | Anonymi Epici et Lyrici |
| LAT9505 | ? | Anonymi Comici et Tragici |
| LAT9510 | ? | Anonymi Grammatici |
| LAT9969 | ? | Vita Iuvenalis |

Comment: This would suggest some sort of chronological order to me? Have only glanced at a few names.

Comment: @Cerberus That sounds possible. Adding some years of birth and death to (some of) these names would probably tell whether that is the case.

Comment: Favorinus is 0067 and Andronicus is 0094? There is no real chronology in those early years. Very strange numbering indeed.